# xorg-x11-drv-intel causes system failure

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, freeze, intel

I am using Fedora 36 with Gnome 42. Sometimes when I start my laptop, the application *Problem Reports* reports "Oops, there seems to be a problem in a component...". When I open it, the `xorg-x11-drv-intel` problem always appears. I installed `xorg-x11-drv-intel` manually, but the behavior does not change. Sometimes the error occurs not only after booting, but while working the screen freezes and I have to force shut down my device via pressing the powerbutton. After rebooting, the same error always occurs as described above. I spend hours trying to figure out how to solve the problem, but I just can't find anything that works.

Here the more detailed problem report:

**reason:**

```bash
WARNING: CPU: 9 PID: 471 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_bios.c:476 init_bdb_block+0x626/0x700 [i915]
```

**backtrace:**

```
WARNING: CPU: 9 PID: 471 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_bios.c:476 init_bdb_block+0x626/0x700 [i915]
Modules linked in: i915(+) drm_buddy drm_display_helper wacom cec nvme intel_ish_ipc(+) ucsi_acpi hid_multitouch crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel nvme_core typec_ucsi serio_raw ttm typec intel_ishtp wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid video pinctrl_tigerlake ip6_tables ip_tables fuse
Unloaded tainted modules: fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1
CPU: 9 PID: 471 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 5.19.6-200.fc36.x86_64 #1
Hardware name: LENOVO 21CD0016GE/21CD0016GE, BIOS N3AET65W (1.30 ) 08/02/2022
RIP: 0010:init_bdb_block+0x626/0x700 [i915]
Code: 8b 7d 08 4c 8b 77 50 4d 85 f6 0f 84 92 00 00 00 e8 0f 7c 30 c4 44 89 e1 4c 89 f2 48 c7 c7 c0 46 70 c0 48 89 c6 e8 8f 78 71 c4 <0f> 0b e9 28 fa ff ff 48 83 c4 28 48 89 df 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e
RSP: 0000:ffffac21009779e0 EFLAGS: 00010282
RAX: 000000000000002c RBX: ffffac2100a748f3 RCX: 0000000000000000
RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffffff85680ff0 RDI: 00000000ffffffff
RBP: ffff8cf20fff0000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffac2100977898
R10: 0000000000000003 R11: ffffffff85f45d88 R12: 000000000000002a
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff8cf205966f20 R15: 0000000000000000
FS:  00007f294f5ba580(0000) GS:ffff8cf54f640000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 0000559b56a3f0d8 CR3: 000000010fdb8006 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
PKRU: 55555554
Call Trace:
```

**cmdline:**

```
BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-5.19.6-200.fc36.x86_64 root=UUID=65e97870-c9e2-4db1-85f5-c278a71e64c4 ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet
```

**package**

```
kernel-core-5.19.6-200.fc36
```

**component:**

```
xorg-x11-drv-intel
```

**type/analyzer:**

```
Kerneloops/abrt-oops
```

My processor is the `12th Gen Intel® Core i7-1260P`. If you need more information, I will provide it.